# Setting apache environment variable using C, function similar to PHP apache_setenv function

Tags: c, apache

I want to set some information in apache environment variable in a c program which I would like to log into custom log file. I am looking for some c function which is similar to PHP `apache_setenv` function.

Pointers would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you using `CGI` ?

Comment: Yes. I want to store some lookup values based on request parameters in a custom log file for analysis. The values set in cgi should be available while writing custom log file.

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look in howto write CGI program, it's probably the way to go. Anyway, I'm not sure if it's possible to set apache vars this way.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by calling this function

```
apr_table_addn(r->subprocess_env, "env_name", "env_value");
```

Where `env_name` and `env_value` are name and value of environment variable respectively.
and `r` is `request_rec` structure pointer object